# Detectar tecla pulsada fuera de formulario c#

Tags: c#

Me preguntaba como se podría detectar cierta tecla, por ejemplo `[F1]`, pero fuera del formulario. Ya que mi idea principal, es que cada vez que se presione dicha tecla, hacer un pantallazo y subirlo a un ftp.

Sin embargo, me encuentro con el problema de que no sé como podría detectar dicha tecla fuera del formulario.

He estado leyendo sobre `GetAsyncKeystate` pero no termino de entenderlo. ¿Es posible que se pueda? ¿Alguna otra alternativa? Gracias.

Comment: fuera del formulario pero estando la aplicacion activa, o fuera del formulario pero visualizando el dektop de windows ? lo pregunto porque una cosa seria usar un evento estando en la aplicacion activa y es diferente si la app no tiene el foco

Comment: Hola @LeandroTuttini Proceso corriendo, sin que la aplicacion tenga focus, por ejemplo, estoy en el navegador y necesito sacar un screenshot, tengo el proceso corriendo, preisono el atajo, digamos ``[F1]`` se hace la captura, se sube por ftp, y abre link. (Básicamente, como gyazo), pero lo que me interesa es saber como podría detectar el ``[F1]`` desde fuera de la aplicación, teniendo ésta corriendo en los procesos.

Comment: Puedes usar lo que se conoce como System Hooks, echa un ojo a estos ejemplos y tutoriales: [https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET) https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C